# Arraylist OutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 4

Tags: java

I'm going through an example on Code Wars. Essentially, taking a number, finding the multiples of 3 and 5 and adding these together. Assuming the number is 10, we'll have 3,5,6,9.

I am at the point where I want to add the multiples together (the foreach loop at the bottom) but I keep getting an OutOfBoundsException. I don't understand how it is reaching index 5! Can someone please explain this to me?

I've seen a few examples of this error on here but can't checking through these I've not been able to resolve the issue, sorry.

```
package Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiplesOf3And5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 10;
    int total = 0;

    List<Integer> multiples = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i + " is a multiple of 3");
            multiples.add(i);
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i + " is a multiple of 5");
            multiples.add(i);
        }
    }       

    for (int j : multiples){
        System.out.println(multiples.get(j));
        System.out.println(multiples.toString());
        total += multiples.get(j);
    }

    System.out.println(total);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for-each loop iterates the values of your List `multiples`, you used each value of the List as index by accident. Fix it as below:

```
for (int j : multiples){
    System.out.println(j);
    System.out.println(multiples.toString());
    total += j;
}
```

The output is:

```
3 is a multiple of 3
5 is a multiple of 5
6 is a multiple of 3
9 is a multiple of 3
3
[3, 5, 6, 9]
5
[3, 5, 6, 9]
6
[3, 5, 6, 9]
9
[3, 5, 6, 9]
23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(j);
```

You are trying to get the `j`th object out of the list, but the you are iterating over the values not the index.

Answer (score 0):

The var `j` holds the current **value** of your iteration, not the current **index** of the iteration.

This should be enough :

```
for (int j : multiples) {
    System.out.println(multiples.toString());
    total += j;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `multiples.get(j)`?

Comment: I shouldn't, good point ;)

Answer (score 0):

> your ArrayList have = 3,6,9(factor of 3) & 5(factor of 5)

so total *4-value reside* into `ArrayList`.

now you are trying to get value from `ArrayList` **not based upon index like 0,1,2,3...**
but you are fetching value from `ArryList` likewise, **multiples.get(3), .get(6)... etc.**

that's why you get error, like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Better to follow this way,

```
 for (int j : multiples){
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(multiples.toString()); // not required but you want then remain it is likewise... or else remove this line
        total += j;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occurring because your for loop is assigning the actual values of your array list. Try this:

```
for(int j = 0, j < multiples.size(), j++) {
  System.out.println(multiples.get(j))
}
```